# Radiation back reaction in classical electrodynamics with point and extended sources

Tags: electromagnetism

I've been doing some research on the topic of radiation reaction force/self force in classical electrodynamics and although there are some discussions on the internet I would like direct answers to these following questions:

1. Is there a rigorous and universally accepted treatment of radiation reaction force in classical electrodynamics for point particles? If so what was the breakthrough that solved the issues plaguing the seminal works such as pre-acceleration and runaway solutions?
2. If we couple Maxwell's equations to a dynamical extended body, such as a charged fluid, do the resulting equations suffer from the typical issues encountered with point sources? And if not, does this treatment predict radiation reaction force that is physically reasonable?
3. Is classical electrodynamics coupled to fluid dynamics a mathematically sound theory? As in, are there results on the existence and uniqueness of solutions in this theory.

Comment: On physics stack exchange questions should contain a single question. Not 3 to 6. Please edit to focus on one question only

Comment: For questions (1) and (2), see [Gralla, Harte, & Wald, Phys. Rev. D **80**, 024031 (2009)](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.80.024031).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, there isn't. All attempts to fix the principle of local conservation of energy in theory combining two incompatible ideas: a) point particles; b) energy interpretation of the Poynting expressions; have lead to contradictions. Point particles do not allow for energy interpretation of the Poynting theorem, because the terms like $\mathbf E\cdot \mathbf j$ in that theorem are too singular. The well-known LAD radiation reaction force does not fix the problem entirely, and introduces new problems, like run-aways, and its various modifications like the integral formulae by Rohrlich are ugly and do not seem to provide for consistent law of local  conservation of energy either.
2. If sources (charge density and current density) are not too singular, then there are no similar obvious issues. Finite charge and current density do not generate obvious problems with conservation of Poynting energy, and one can even explain radiation reaction as result of EM forces due to parts of the body acting on other parts. This is how Lorentz/Abraham derived the Lorentz-Abraham force in the first place - it is part of the EM force on extended body due to itself.
3. Well is fluid dynamics itself a mathematically sound theory? The Navier-Stokes equations are difficult to analyze.

Comment: In physics, it doesn't matter whether models are mathematically sound: it only matters whether they match the phenomena. The pursuit of mathematical soundness *sometimes* leads to better models, but it isn't a sure thing.

Comment: For your question 1, look at https://doi.org/10.1142/S0217751X23500057

Comment: @JerroldFranklin I do not have access to the paper. Effect of the LAD radiation reaction force on motion of a charged particle in external field is known to be negligible and unmeasurable in practice. However, that calculation is based on inconsistent theory, thus the more interesting question is how to make the classical theory internally consistent.

Comment: If you "do not have access to the paper", how do you know "that calculation is based on inconsistent theory"? I do not think I am allowed to post the published paper, but I will email my own version to anyone who sends a request to <j.franklin@temple.edu>.

Comment: Because I meant the standard calculation. I don't know what is in your paper.